# Copy Test .pdf file & rename to all current .pdf files in directory

Tags: powershell

What I need to do is copy a test.pdf file as each of the current .pdf files that are in a specific directory already.

For example the directory has xyz.pdf, rgh.pdf, bne.pdf, etc.

test.pdf needs to be renamed as xyz.pdf, rgh.pdf, bne.pdf, etc.
All of the .pdf files should have the exact same content, which is why I need to rename test.pdf as each of the .pdf files in the directory.

This is what I've tried so far. It copies the test file "V2500SB.pdf" to the correct directory. There are two .pdf files in the directory, but it is not renaming "V2500SB.pdf" as the files in the directory. Also it is stopping after it runs the first file. Any ideas?

```
try
{
$PDFDir = "D:\V2500Test\*"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path ($PDFDir) 
$ErrorActionPreference= 'continue'
$NewPDFDir = "D:\V2500SB.pdf"
$NewPDF = "V2500SB.pdf"

if (Test-Path -Path "$PDFDir") 
{  

# Code for directory not empty
    # enumerate the items array
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
     Write-Host $item.Name 
    Copy-Item -Path $NewPDFDir -destination $PDFDir
    Rename-Item $NewPDFDir + $NewPDF $PDFDir + $item -Force

    }
}   
else 
{
Write-Host "No file to move"
 exit
}

} #end of try 
  catch  #Catch any fatal errors and send an email with description
    {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    $ErrorName = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName  

    $ExceptionBody = @"
    Exception Name: $ErrorName
    Exception Type: $FailedItem 
    Exception Message: $ErrorMessage 
"@

    } # end of catch    
        finally
        {  
        }
```

Comment: Comment out the catch block and see if your scripts fails with an error.

Comment: Are you trying to create a totally new set of files in a folder with the same names as the files in another folder? Or are you trying to replace the contents of each file in an existing folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but I think it's one of two things:

Are you trying to replace the contents of all the files in a folder with the contents of 'test.pdf'? If that's the case, you just need to use Copy-Item with the destination path set to the original filename:

```
$PDFDir = "D:\V2500Test"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $PDFDir

$NewPDF = "V2500SB.pdf"

if(Test-Path -Path $PDFDir)
{
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        Write-Host $item.Name 
        Copy-Item $NewPDF -Destination $item.FullName
    }
}
```

Or are you trying to fill a new folder with files that have the names of files from another folder, but which all have the contents of 'test.pdf? In that case, the answer is similar but you have to build a new path (using Join-Path):

```
$PDFDir = "D:\SourceFolder"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $PDFDir
$NewPDF = "V2500SB.pdf"

$PDFDir2 = "D:\V2500Test"

if(Test-Path -Path $PDFDir2)
{
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        Write-Host $item.Name 
        Copy-Item $NewPDF -Destination (Join-Path $PDFDir2 -ChildPath $item.Name) 
    }
}
```

Either way, you don't need to do Copy-Item and then Rename-Item; Copy-Item can handle that in one step.

Comment: Thank you @E.Z. Hart the first example is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have too much stuff in your rename command...

Rename-Item $NewPDFDir + $NewPDF $PDFDir + $item

This is what you're trying...

```
Rename-Item D:\V2500SB.pdfV2500SB.pdf D:\V2500Test\*whateverWasFound.pdf -Force
```

Also the reason it's copying just once is because you copy using the same source and destination each time...

I strongly suggest to try your command with value to see what is actually going on...